# Is there a way to show the latest price of a product in Google Sheets when the product webpage contains dynamic content?

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping

I want to compare the prices of different products, but the IMPORTDATA/IMPORTXML function in Google Sheets doesn't work because of dynamic content (marketing banners, cookie consent, etc.) on the product webpage.

ChatGPT suggested to add this script to the Google Apps Script, but it made no difference:

```
function fetchData(url) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var content = response.getContentText();
  var doc = XmlService.parse(content);
  
  // Modify the following lines to match the structure of the website
  var title = doc.getRootElement().getChild("head").getChild("title").getText();
  var amount = doc.getRootElement().getChild("body").getChild("div").getChild("span").getText();
  var price = doc.getRootElement().getChild("body").getChild("div").getChild("p").getText();
  
  return [title, amount, price];
}

function updateData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();

  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    var url = values[i][1]; // Assuming URLs are in column B

    if (url !== "") {
      var data = fetchData(url);
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, 2, 1, data.length).setValues([data]);
    }
  }
}
```

**Can someone help to obtain this kind of table where I only need to add the URL and the other cells will be automatically filled and updated?**

Column 1: Name of product
Column 2: URL of product
Column 3: amount in 1 package
Column 4: the current price

*Example*

*Column 1: Kruidvat Pure & Soft 2 Newborn Mini Luiers Midpack

Column 2: https://www.kruidvat.be/nl/kruidvat-pure-soft-2-newborn-mini-luiers-volumedoos/p/5662084

Column 3: 186

Column 4: 29,99*

PS: Yes, I'm a soon to be mom and want to compare and track all diaper prices in Belgium, but want to avoid to subscribe to e-mail services :-D

Thank you!